# Tikz Externalize Wont Work (MWE)

Tags: tikz-external, shell-escape, texpad

I have quite a large document that I am working on and tikz externalize has stopped working. Since I have been messing with formatting, I am hoping it is a problem on my end and not a glitch. The following MWE gives an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[]

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
\draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (3.9,3.9);
\draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};
\draw[color=red] plot[id=x] function{x} 
    node[right] {$f(x) =x$};
\end{tikzpicture}

Text.

\end{document}
```

Here is the error it gives

```
Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -
interaction=batchmode -jobname ""Honors Template"-figure0" 
"\def\tikzexternalrealjob{"Honors Template"}\input{"Honors Template"}"'
 did NOT result in a usable output file '"Honors Template"-figure0' 
(expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). 
Please verify that you have enabled system calls. 
For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'.
 Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. 
Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 
'"Honors Template"-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try 
to typeset the picture.
```

I am using (up to date) Texpad on OS X. I have shell escape always allowed, shell escape enabled for this project, and hide files disabled. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can compile your MWE successfully with `pdflatex -shell-escape [...]` on Arch Linux with TeX Live 2016.Have you tried cleaning out all existing externalized pictures and forcing them all to be re-compiled?
Does the above example fail just in the directory of your bigger project, or does it also fail when you put it into a clean, empty, new directory?

Comment: @alpenwasser I have tried deleting everything but the tex file and recompiling. I think I tried using `pdflatex -shell-escape [...]`, but I'm not I put it in the right place.

Comment: Add `\the\pdfshellescape` to your document body, compile and tell us what it prints.

Comment: Compilation with `pdflatex -shell-escape %.tex` works for me too. Clean old generated files (with Texmaker: Ctrl+Alt+A).

Comment: Ok so after a line by line analysis, it seems that the problem was a type where I had written `\usepackage[imakeidx]` (with an extra i). I copy and pasted that MWE directly, so, if that was the problem, then there is some sort of bug in Texpad.

Comment: Your MWE doesn't contain that line with or without an extra `i`.